# How to convert an array from string to integer

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I have an array "string()" with 3 element (2,5,6)
How do I convert all of element from string to int?
I tried CInt and Array.ConvertAll  but they didn't work.
Please show me the way to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have not said what type of problem you are having using [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.90).aspx) or shown your implementation of it, but this works for me.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim mystringArray As String() = New String() {"2", "5", "6"}
        Dim myintArray As Integer()

        myintArray = Array.ConvertAll(mystringArray, New Converter(Of String, Integer)(AddressOf StringToInteger))
    End Sub

    Function StringToInteger(st As String) As Integer
        Return CInt(st)
    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the List(Of T).ConvertAll

```
Dim stringList = {'2','5','6'}.ToList
Dim intList = stringList.ConvertAll(Function(str) Int32.Parse(str))
```

Comment: @user2584427, make sure to add `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: It still doesn't work after importing System.Collections.Generic

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim stringList() As String = {"2", "5", "6"}' string array 
Dim intList() As Integer = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}'integer array initialized with 0
For i As Integer = 0 To stringList.Length - 1
    intList(i) = CInt(stringList(i))
Next
'Display the list
For i = 0 To intList.Length - 1
    MsgBox(intList(i))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm:

```
    Dim strArr As New List(Of String)(New String() {"2", "5", "6"})
    Dim intList As List(Of Integer) = strArr.ConvertAll(New Converter(Of String, Integer)(AddressOf Integer.Parse))
```

No need to define a custom parser. Have look at its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) as well:

Answer (score 0):

My VB is rusty but I would do something like this:

```
intList = (From s in stringList Select CInt(s)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lambda,

```
Dim intList As IList(Of Integer)
Dim list1 = "1,2,3".Split(",")
intList = list1.ConvertAll(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s))
```

or

```
Dim intList As IList(Of Integer)
Dim list1 = "1,2,3".Split(",")
intList = list1.ConvertAll(AddressOf Integer.Parse)
```