# Convert String to Integer, Error in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a array with type of string  and I'm trying to convert it to a new integer array by the code below

```
  intlist = list1.ConvertAll(New Converter(Of String, Integer)(AddressOf Integer.Parse))
```

But I always get this error, Visual Studio 2013 doesn't recognize the "ConvertAll".

```
 Error  1   Argument not specified for parameter 'converter' of 'Public Shared Function ConvertAll(Of TInput, TOutput)(array() As TInput, converter As System.Converter(Of TInput, TOutput)) As TOutput()'. C:\Users\Louis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DataGridCopyPaste\DataGridCopyPaste\Form1.vb   17  19  DataGridCopyPaste
```

Comment: I have tested this code and it works (even in VS 2010): `Dim list1 As New List(Of String) From {"1", "2", "3"} Dim intlist As List(Of Int32) = list1.ConvertAll(New Converter(Of String, Integer)(AddressOf Integer.Parse))`. I also don't understand "Visual Studio 2013 doesn't recognize the 'ConvertAll'" in combination with your error: "Argument not specified". It seems that it actually *recognizes* the method but doesn't like a parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an array from string to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856591/how-to-convert-an-array-from-string-to-integer)

Comment: Please do not repost your question, if someone's answer to a previous question doesn't work, address it to them in the comments of their answer.

Comment: what type is `list1`? Not an `IList` presumably.